# EC2 IAM - restrict CreateTags permission to instances which were started from an AMI with a particular tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Does anyone know of a way to create the following permission on AWS IAM:

- Allows tagging of any EC2 instance, on the condition that:

  - The AMI from which the instance was created has the tag "foo" with the value "bar".

I can see how to create a general `CreateTags` permission, and a permission to tag a particular instance specified by instance id, but I'm so far struggling to find a way to create the restriction I want.

Comment: I tried adding `"Condition": {"StringEquals": {"iam:ResourceTag/Environment": "${var.environment}"}}` but so far no luck

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your policy:

```
"Condition": {"StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/foo": "bar"}}
```

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-ec2-resource-tags/

Comment: Actually, this is testing the tag on the instance, not on the AMI used to create the instance, so it may not apply to your use case.